# How does the password reset model work?

Tags: security, email

Email providers use secret questions as a part of the process to reset a user's password, when the user doesn't remember it, right? Generally, how does this security model work? How do the security questions identify the user?

Generally: how does the reset password model work? What is its architecture?

Comment: Your question is disjointed and uses poor grammar. Please reword

Comment: My apologies for the poor grammar.

Comment: First of all email providers give the chance to the users to reset their passwords with a set of secret questions. The user chooses one question and ansewers it.If he forget his password he just answer the secret questi

Answer (score 0):

Basically on registration, the user picks and answers the questions, which are saved in the database.

When the users forgets his or her password, they are asked those questions, and the idea is that only the user would know the answer to those questions. If they answer them correctly, they can be trusted to be the actual user and a new password can be issued.